# Hiding status bar in one view hides it in all views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm using this code `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];` in `viewDidLoad` and nothing else, to hide the status bar in my modal view. But when I come back to the previous view with `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` the status bar is hidden in all the views. Of course I don't want this behavior. I understand that this is a simple question and might be a possible duplicate.
Anyway, thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to unhide the status bar in `viewWillDisappear` or somewhere else to put it back when you leave that view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that `sharedApplication` (singleton) is your application, so you just told your app to hide the status bar. If you want it to show somewhere else, you need to `setStatusBarHidden:NO` there. Hope this helps.